# Binomial distribution problem with subtractive factor growth

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have a problem that can be modeled using the binomial distribution.

I want to know the probability that over  *n* trials I will see *k* successes with a probability of success $P_s$ and a probability of failure $P_f$

This is pretty straightforward stuff:

$$
\binom{n}{k} {P_s}^k (P_f)^{n-k}
$$

However there is also a probability that an event will occur within the trials that subtracts from the total number of successes.  This event is exclusive of both a success and a failure, and the probability is represented by $P_r$

Put more simply, in each trial there are three possible outcomes:

Success *S* : counts as 1 success

Failure *F* : counts as 0 successes

Reduce *R* : counts as -1 successes

My first approach to this problem would be to generate the table of all possible outcomes (at length $3^k$) and compute the probability of occurrence for each combination that satisfies the requirements, however this approach is obviously suboptimal

How can I adjust this formula in such a way that it accomodates scaling subtractive cases appropriately?

Comment: Do you know about the multinomial distribution ?

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking about it wrong, but I figured I could use the multinomial distribution to determine the likelihood of occurence of each case, but not the aggregate.... I suppose I might be able to do something along the lines of precomputing conditions, and then using a multinomial distribution against all of those conditions

Comment: I'm aware of the multinomial distribution, but it's not immediately obvious to me how I could leverage it in this case

Comment: Nevermind, I now see what you're saying, it's the correct solution to the problem (even though it's not single state).  And I feel dumb.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I went with in this case was actually to look at all of the possible outcomes through simulation.

Essentially for every sample of size N, I computed the likelihood of that sample's occurrence, and added it to the end score